# modelAttribute and path in a form when using a wrapper of a list of entities and c:foreach loop

Tags: java, spring, forms

I plan to create a view with multiple forms tha are created of a list of model objects. As it is desribed in an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32666512/5673289 I created a wrapper object for the list:

*src/main/java/tk/trzczy/gallery/wrapperObject/GalleryForm.java*

```
package tk.trzczy.gallery.wrapperObject;

import tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.Image;

import java.util.List;

public class GalleryForm {
    private List<Image> gallery;

    public GalleryForm(List<Image> gallery) {
        this.gallery = gallery;
    }

    public List<Image> getGallery() {
        return gallery;
    }

    public void setGallery(List<Image> gallery) {
        this.gallery = gallery;
    }
}
```

and improved a controller in this way:

*src/main/java/tk/trzczy/gallery/controllers/ImageController.java*

```
package tk.trzczy.gallery.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.Image;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.services.ImageService;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.services.ImageCategoryService;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Date;


import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.wrapperObject.GalleryForm;

@Controller
public class ImageController {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ImageService imageService;

//(...)
    @RequestMapping("/gallery/edit")
    public String getImagesToEdit(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("images", new GalleryForm(imageService.getAllImages()));
        return "editGallery";
    }
//(...)
}
```

And tried to use proper `modelAttribute` and `path` values in jsp file, but did not succeed:

*src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/editGalleryPage.jsp*

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="g" uri="/WEB-INF/date-format-tag.tld" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/resource/css/editGallery.css" />"/>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <c:forEach items="${images.gallery}" var="image" varStatus="vs">
        <form:form modelAttribute="images" action="/images/edit/${image.id}" id="image" class="image"
                   method="post">
            <form:input path="images.gallery[${vs.index}].url" id="image-${image.id}" style="width: 525px;"
                        class=" form:input-large"
                        name='url' value="${image.url}"/>
            <input type="submit">
            <p><form:errors path="url" cssClass="alert alert-danger"/></p>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error was

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'images' of bean class [tk.trzczy.gallery.wrapperObject.GalleryForm]: Bean property 'images' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?` 
Here it is a *pom.xml* file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tk.trzczy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspect.version>1.9.2</aspect.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5.2</c3p0.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- servlets and jps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for rest services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspect.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspect.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To Send Email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <c:forEach items="${images.gallery}" var="image" varStatus="vs">
            <form:form modelAttribute="images" action="/images/edit/${image.id}" id="image" class="image" method="post">
                <form:input path="gallery[${vs.index}].url" id="image-${image.id}" style="width: 525px;"
                    class=" form:input-large"
                    name='url' value="${image.url}"/>
                <input type="submit">
                <p><form:errors path="gallery[${vs.index}].url" cssClass="alert alert-danger"/></p>
            </form:form>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem was the path specified for `form:input` which started with `images.` but since the modeAttribute is `images` it needed to start with `gallery`.